# Cannot replace substrings using replace function in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a string in a column and want to replace ROLE_ADMIN roles from the column below is running successfully **"ROLE_DEVELOPER,ROLE_PRV1,ROLE_TEST,ROLE_VISITOR,ROLE_DOC,ROLE_ADMIN"** using replace

```
    **select REPLACE('ROLE_DEVELOPER,ROLE_PRV1,ROLE_TEST,ROLE_VISITOR,ROLE_DOC,ROLE_ADMIN -COPY',',ROLE_ADMIN','')**
```

However there is a usecase as below here I want data should be unchanged as ROLE_ADMIN -COPY is a different role
**"ROLE_DEVELOPER,ROLE_PRV1,ROLE_TEST,ROLE_VISITOR,ROLE_DOC,ROLE_ADMIN -COPY"**
but its printing **ROLE_DEVELOPER,ROLE_PRV1,ROLE_TEST,ROLE_VISITOR,ROLE_DOC -COPY**

Can anyone help in tackling this ?
Note:- I can use only one generic query

Comment: Do three replace (s).  First replace ROLE_ADMIN -COPY into something else like SUMANT then replace ROLE_ADMIN by '', then put back SUMANT into ROLE_ADMIN -COPY.  Option 2 is you can do REGEX. Thanks.

Comment: Use `REGEXP_REPLACE()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surround the list with the delimiter characters and then replace the term and the leading and trailing delimiters with a single delimiter to ensure you match an entire term and then trim the string to remove the surrounding delimiters.

In Oracle, that would be:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(
         BOTH ',' FROM
         REPLACE(
           ','||role_list||',',
           ',ROLE_ADMIN,',
           ','
         )
       ) AS updated_list
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (role_list) AS
SELECT 'ROLE_DEVELOPER,ROLE_PRV1,ROLE_TEST,ROLE_VISITOR,ROLE_DOC,ROLE_ADMIN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ROLE_DEVELOPER,ROLE_PRV1,ROLE_TEST,ROLE_VISITOR,ROLE_DOC,ROLE_ADMIN_COPY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ROLE_DEVELOPER,ROLE_PRV1,ROLE_TEST,ROLE_VISITOR,ROLE_DOC,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_ADMIN_COPY' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| UPDATED_LIST |
| --- |
| ROLE_DEVELOPER,ROLE_PRV1,ROLE_TEST,ROLE_VISITOR,ROLE_DOC |
| ROLE_DEVELOPER,ROLE_PRV1,ROLE_TEST,ROLE_VISITOR,ROLE_DOC,ROLE_ADMIN_COPY |
| ROLE_DEVELOPER,ROLE_PRV1,ROLE_TEST,ROLE_VISITOR,ROLE_DOC,ROLE_ADMIN_COPY |

[Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Gm8Sxa-_)

---

In MySQL, you need to change to use `CONCAT` rather than `||`:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(
         BOTH ',' FROM
         REPLACE(
           CONCAT(',',role_list,','),
           ',ROLE_ADMIN,',
           ','
         )
       ) AS updated_list
FROM   table_name;
```

[MySQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ng3SRXXW)

Comment: @sumantkumar This removes the `ROLE_ADMIN` role and does not remove the `ROLE_ADMIN_COPY` role; that appears to be exactly what the question asks. If you are trying to get something else then please consider that maybe the usecase in the question is not explained sufficiently.